# SQL order or arrange

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query

```
SELECT  s.question, s.answer
  FROM Survey s
```

and the return like this

```
question                                      answer
Do you get support for this program A?          no
Do you get support for this program B?          no
If no, do you want to learn more program A?     yes
If no, do you want to learn more program B?     yes
```

I want the return on question column become

```
question                                      answer
Do you get support for this program A?          no
If no, do you want to learn more program A?     yes
Do you get support for this program B?          no
If no, do you want to learn more program B?     yes
```

Any work around. Thank you.

Comment: Please explain the ordering that you want?  How do you know the questions are related?

Comment: just want to users to see the questions more understand.? the question just created for the survey . If use order by ASC or DESC then they will show in alphabet .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be adding an additional column to identify which questions go together.

```
category question                                      answer
  1      Do you get support for this program A?          no
  2      Do you get support for this program B?          no
  1      If no, do you want to learn more program A?     yes
  2      If no, do you want to learn more program B?     yes
```

Now you can do this query:

```
SELECT  s.question, s.answer
FROM Survey s 
ORDER BY s.category, s.answer
```

Comment: @Tsang Do you have created and additional column named 'group' ?

Comment: @Tsang  Apologies, looks like group is a reserved word. Please use the column name 'category'.

Comment: I can see what u mean. I thought about it but  i have more questions  already. I just try to quick way without to create more work

Answer (score 0):

You could order by the last character and then by the whole question:

```
select s.*
from survey s
order by right(question, 1), question;
```

Comment: It should be right(question, 2) instead of right(question, 1), because the last character is the '?', although I believe that the best solution would be a proper structure identifying the questions that should go together.

Comment: then i got question                                                  answer
If no, do you want to learn more program A?? yes
Do you get support for this program A?               no
Do you get support for this program B?           no
If no, do you want to learn more program B?         yes

Comment: @Tsang Yes, but it would only work for those questions, because it orders by the last two characters: A? and B?. When you add real questions, instead of program A and program B, it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
SELECT Question, Answer
FROM
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Answer) % 2 RN
  FROM
  (
    VALUES
    ('Do you get support for this program A?',          0),
    ('Do you get support for this program B?',          0),
    ('If no, do you want to learn more program A?',     1),
    ('If no, do you want to learn more program B?',     1)
  ) T(Question, Answer)
) TT
ORDER BY RN, Answer;
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c62c3e70ecd876970f604a72e4e30d86)

Comment: It works. But I do have more values not just 4 values. Thank you for your support.